# Unusuall way to fill multiple rows in an array non recursively?

Tags: c

Hi I m debugging a C app and seing this strange behavior in an array of 10 rows and 4 columns:

```
void fillArray(int *B){ 
 //DEBUG
    printArray(B,10,4);//printing all items 0's
    B[3,0] =  3;
    printArray(B,10,4); // results in B[0,0] = 3 , B[1,0] = 3 , B[2,0] = 3  , B[3,0]= 3 , ...
                    // Rest values remains zero.
}



 void printArray(int *B,int imax,int jmax){
     printf(" \n --- Check---");    

    for(i=0;i<imax;i++){
        for(j=0;j<jmax;j++){            
            printf(" \n Check: B[%d,%d]=%d ",i,j,B[i,j]);
        }
    }    
}
```

Why does value 3 is inserted in every row of the table for column 0 ?

Comment: is your code so badly indented, or you just failed to format it here?

Comment: `B[3,0] =  3;` This is not the way to index a 2dimensional array.

Comment: Please show the definition of `B`. I don't quite understand the question; there is only one writing access to `B`.

Comment: And you're making the same error when printing it.  `3,0` evaluates to `0` so you're only setting the `[0]` element.  Similarly when printing, you're only ever looking at the `[j]` element.

Comment: omg!! I m total noob!!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the expression `3, 0` to index the array. That expression has the value 0 (it's using the sequence operator, the value of which is the value of the last expression, in this cas e a constant 0). To index a multi-dimensional array in C, you need to use something like `m[a][b]`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the syntax for two-dimensional arrays is:

```
B[3][0] = 3
```

rather than:

```
B[3,0] =  3;`
```

`,` is the comma operator which has an other meaning (basically, the value of the expression `a, b` is `b`).

Answer (score 0):

Because the `,` operator discards all the operands except the last. So this

```
B[3,0] = 3;
```

is effectively

```
B[0] = 3;
```

and how many columns does your table have? since it's an `int *` I doubt that you have a table. The suggested syntax

```
B[3][0] = 3;
```

is wrong too, because `B[3]` has type `int` and you cannot index an `int`.